# Normalize vs Standarization with percentage data

Tags: clustering, standardization

I'm studying access patterns to a facility with clustering.

My variables are percentages. For example, for each user, I have the percentage of access 'in time' versus late, or the percentage of using a particular door access by weekday (percentage of accesses on Monday, Tuesday...).

Should my data be scaled through standarization (mean 0 deviation 1) or normalization (min-max 0-1)? Or it's not necessary, as all values come in same scale (0-1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the variables are all on a 0 to 1 scale, standardizing will change the meaning and may change the clustering.  For example, if one variable is always above 0.9, and another variable ranges over the whole of 0 to 1, then they will look very different in raw and standardized forms.

This will change distances, and thus change clustering.

If you want each variable to be equally "important" (for some meaning of "important") then standardize. If you want the importance to reflect the actual data, then don't.

My inclination is to not standardize, but it's up to you. I am basing that on the idea that, if nearly everyone does something, then that thing is not usually important. But ... it depends on what you want to use the clustering for.

Comment: (+1) "*it depends on what you want to use the clustering for.*" **Preach.**